# Search specific column in CSV file with Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

Currently my program is functions to search for specific text values in the imported csv file and change them to the desired value, and outputs a csv file. the problem I am having right now: is there a way to limit searches to specific columns so that if for example if 'hob' the find text and we replace that with 'TEST', the city field of hoboken will change to Testobken. I am pretty new to python so I apologize if this is an easy fix. Here is my current code.

```
import csv
ifile = open('testbook.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(ifile,delimiter='\t')
ofile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t')

findlist = ['Australia', 'Mexico', 'United States', 'hob']
replacelist = ['Kangaroo', 'Spider Monkey', 'Eagle', 'Test']

rep = dict(zip(findlist, replacelist))

def findReplace(find, replace):
    s = ifile.read()
    for item, replacement in zip(findlist, replacelist):
        s = s.replace(item, replacement)
   ofile.write(s)

for item in findlist:
    findReplace(item, rep[item])

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

Example Input:
Australia   Australia   United States   United States
Mexico  Mexico  Hoboken

Example Output:
Kangaroo    Kangaroo    Eagle   Eagle
Spider Monkey   Spider Monkey   Testoken

Comment: Could you add a short input/output example?  Ilustrating those replacements.

Comment: @GermanoLodi added

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex. The `\b` means you'll only replace full words. So something like:

```
import re

def findReplace(s, find, replace):
    s = re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % find , replace, s)
    return s


s = "rest and don't get arrested"
s = findReplace(s, "rest", "run")
print(s)
```

This will print `run and don't get arrested`.